# Suppose that $G$ is a commutative group, and define $f∶G → G$ by $f(a) = a^{−1}$ . Prove or disprove: $f$ is an isomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

I think it is isomorphic but I don't how to actually prove it. I think it is because $a$ would go to $a^{-1}$, $b$ to $b^{-1}$, $e$ to $e$ etc.

Comment: Well, what do you have to check to show that a homomorphism is an isomorphism?

Comment: This basically boils down to answer: do we have $(ab)^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1}\;$ *in this case* ?

Comment: @lul I think that's the other way: he **first** has to check whether that is a homomorphism...

Comment: You would have to prove it's a homomorphism and then prove it's 1-1 and onto. Can you prove these are all true?

Comment: @DonAntonio  Absolutely correct.  I should have written "what do you have to check to show that a function is a group isomorphism."

Answer (score 2):

Let $f$ send $a$ to $a^{-1}$. Therefore, $$f(ab)=(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1}=f(a)f(b),$$ so that $f$ is an homomorphism (that's why we must consider $G$ as an abelian group). To prove that $f$ is injective, let $f(a)=f(b)$. Therefore, $a^{-1}=b^{-1}$. Because one element can't have more than one inverse, $a=b$. To prove it is surjective, let $a$ be any element of our group. Clearly, $f(a^{-1})=a$, so that the image of $f$ is the whole group. As a consequence, we have an isomorphism.

Comment: Perhaps you meant " so that $\;f\;$ is a **homomorphism**"

Comment: why is $(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$?

Comment: @ty That is **always** so in **any** group. Prove using uniqueness of inverse.\

Comment: More generally, if $G$ is not necessarily abelian, a similar proof shows the inverse map gives an isomorphism $G \to G^{op}$, where $G^{op}$ is the group with the same underlying set but with reversed multiplication, i.e. $(a \cdot b)_{G^{op}} := (b \cdot a)_G$.

Comment: @DonAntonio, yes, I did! Edited it just now.

Comment: Very interesting note, @DanielSchepler.

Comment: thank you all for your help, group theory is rough for me as my first proof class

Comment: @TPace So, would this be an correct proof? Let there be two possible inverses $a^{-1},b^{-1}\in G$ to $a\in G$. Let $n$ be the neutral element. We have $$a^{-1}=a^{-1}n=a^{-1}(ab^{-1})=(a^{-1}a)b^{-1}=nb^{-1}=b^{-1}.$$ So the inverse is unique. And secondly $$(b^{-1}a^{-1})(ab)=b^{-1}(a^{-1}(ab))=b^{-1}((a^{-1}a)b)=b^{-1}(nb)=b^{-1}b=n.$$ So the inverse to $(ab)$ is $b^{-1}a^{-1}$.

Comment: Your proofs are both correct. In fact, you could also say, in the first proof, that $aa^{-1}=ab^{-1}$, so that $a^{-1}=b^{-1}$. However, the way you proved it was more elementary, which is also fine.

Answer (score 0):

To prove whether or not a function is an isomorphism, you need to answer 2 questions : is it a homomorphism and is it bijective?

Homomorphism :

Prove that for any $a,b \in G$ you have $f(a\cdot b) = f(a)\cdot f(b)$

In order to prove that, you will need the fact that G is commutative.

Bijection :

There are many ways to show this. You could prove that $f$ is invertible OR that $f$ is injective and surjective.